# Excel VBA: Restart Loop Counter

Tags: vba, excel, loops

**Hi, I am trying to restart my loop counter(iColumn). I am looping through the columns to replace multiple words in a template(TemplateSheet). Is it possible to restart the loop counter after looping through all the columns(inside loop).**

My only problem is after incrementing the row value, it goes back to the loop(columns) then the **value of iColumn becomes 4** and terminates the inside loop.

```
While Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(iRow, 1).Value <> ""

   While Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(1, iColumn) <> ""

      sFind = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(1, iColumn)

      sReplacement = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(iRow, iColumn)

      sTemplate = Replace(sTemplate, sFind, sReplacement)

      iColumn = iColumn + 1

Wend
      Sheets("OutputSheet").Cells(iRow, 1) = sTemplate
      iRow = iRow + 1
   Wend
```

**The problem was solved in restarting the loop counter. But now I have to overwrite the replacement function because it doesn't store the new replaced data.**

Comment: What if you add `iColumn = 1` after `iRow = iRow + 1`? Also, should the definition of `sFind` not go right before entering the inner loop?

Comment: Thank you so much @loannis!

But I still have another problem. I have to overwrite the replacement function. Because it doesn't store the next new replaced data.

Comment: Could you add to the question what is that you trying to *achieve* in addition to why your approach does not work? You can get better help this way.. I sense that what you are trying to do can be done in a far easier way.  See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If FreeMan's answer has solved your original issue, it would be nice if you accept it/upvote it.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to find/replace? It looks like you are looking in the rows below for a string that's in your first column. Then you are replacing that entire cell with the text from the first row. Is that correct?

Comment: I agree with @Ioannis - if you let us know what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to help you find a better solution. especially after Tony L pointed out that this is the 2nd nearly identical question you've accepted an answer for.

Comment: Also, don't replace the broken code in your OP with now functional code, it only serves to confuse and slow down those who come along later and are trying to figure out if this Q/A will help them. You can post the working code after the broken code, with a note that this is the fix, if you feel that is really going to be helpful.

Comment: I have three sheets of data: DataSheet, TemplateSheet, OutputSheet.

I am trying to loop through every column(DataSheet) to find the codename to be replaced(the same codename on the TemplateSheet). I will get the replacement words from "DataSheet" . Then I will store the new template in the "OutputSheet". 

Now my problem is, I don't know how to overwrite the replacement function for the new template. The output stores the same data of template from the first loop and it never replaces,

@TonyL.

Comment: Looking at your old post as well, if I'm understanding what you're trying to do, and I'm not sure I am, it looks like you are searching Datasheet for a string in the first cell of TemplateSheet. If you find that string, you replace it with the string in the first cell of Datasheet and output that to OutputSheet. If you don't find that string, you just output the same data to from Datasheet to OutputSheet. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, And I have solved my problem. Thanks everyone for the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply reset the value of `iColumn` to whatever your initial value needs to be. I assumed `1`.

```
While Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(iRow, 1).Value <> ""
   While Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(1, iColumn) <> ""
      sFind = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(1, iColumn)
      sReplacement = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(iRow, iColumn)
      sTemplate = Replace(sTemplate, sFind, sReplacement)
      iColumn = iColumn + 1
   Wend
   MsgBox sTemplate
   iRow = iRow + 1
   iColumn = 1
Wend
```

You can simplify your code a bit like this:

```
While Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(iRow, 1).Value <> ""
   While Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(1, iColumn) <> ""
      sTemplate = Replace(sTemplate, Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(1, iColumn), Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(iRow, iColumn))
      iColumn = iColumn + 1
   Wend
   MsgBox sTemplate
   iRow = iRow + 1
   iColumn = 1
Wend
```

Finally, note that the location of your `MsgBox` call you will only get the final value of `sTemplate`, not any of the intermediate values. That may, of course, be what you're after.

Comment: @bigbryan Looks like I gave you a similar answer on the loop the other day. Did that not fix your loop? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30673171/3347858

Comment: Yes sir @TonyL . Thank you Sir. But I still have one problem.
 
I have three sheets of data: DataSheet, TemplateSheet, OutputSheet. I am trying to loop through every column(DataSheet) to find the codename to be replaced(the same codename on the TemplateSheet). I will get the replacement words from "DataSheet" . Then I will store the new template in the "OutputSheet". Now my problem is, I don't know how to overwrite the replacement function for the new template. The output stores the same data of template from the first loop and it never replaces,
Thank you!

Comment: That should probably have been your question in the first place: I'm trying to do "X". Here's what I've done so far. Here's the problem I'm running into.

Answer (score 1):

If sTemplate has the value that you want in the cell, then you'll need to set the cell to that data as well like so:

```
Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(iRow, iColumn) = sTemplate
```

Here's the whole loop:

```
While Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(iRow, 1).Value <> ""
    While Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(1, iColumn) <> ""
        sFind = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(1, iColumn)
        sReplacement = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(iRow, iColumn)
        sTemplate = Sheets("TemplateSheet").Cells(1, 1)
        Sheets("OutputSheet").Cells(iRow, iColumn) = Replace(sReplacement, sTemplate, sFind)
        iColumn = iColumn + 1
    Wend
    MsgBox sTemplate
    iRow = iRow + 1
    iColumn = 1
Wend
```

Comment: @bigbryan Does sTemplate currently get the correct value you want in the OutputSheet?

Comment: @bigbryan, I also changed the order of the parameters in the Replace function after making some assumptions.